# How to keep DT's Caption widget centered relative to mainPanel's width?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt, shinyjs

I am trying to keep the caption in a centered position- relative to the window/`mainPanel`'s width at all time. At the moment when I collapse the `sidebarPanel` on wide tables, only then the caption remains centered. But when `sidebarPanel` is uncollapsed, unlike other `DT` widgets, caption changes it's "position" and appears on the right hand side. Please assist.

Here is a reprex:

global.R

```r
options(scipen = 99999)

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

xyz_query <- dplyr::bind_cols(mtcars, mtcars)
```

ui.R

```r
fluidPage(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
  
  navbarPage( 
    
    id = "navbar",
    title= "xyz",
    windowTitle = "xyz test",
    
    tabPanel("Dataset",
             
             div(style="display:inline-block",shinyWidgets::materialSwitch(inputId = "toggleSidebar", label = "Filter Panel: ",
                                                                           value = TRUE, status = "warning")),
             
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 id = "Sidebar",
                 br(),
                 br()
                 
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 id = "main_panel",
                 DT::DTOutput('panel1_data')
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```r
function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$toggleSidebar, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar", condition = input$toggleSidebar)
    if(!isTRUE(input$toggleSidebar)) {
      shinyjs::runjs("$('#main_panel').removeClass('col-sm-8').addClass('col-sm-12')")
    } else {
      shinyjs::runjs("$('#main_panel').removeClass('col-sm-12').addClass('col-sm-8')")
    }
    
  })
  
  output$panel1_data <- DT::renderDT(server = FALSE, {
    DT::datatable(xyz_query,
                  extensions = c('Buttons'),
                  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center; color:black; font-size:150% ;',
                                                     'MTCARS mtCARS mTcArS MTcars'),
                  options = list(scrollY = 600,
                                 scrollX = TRUE,
                                 dom =  '<"float-left"l><"float-right"f>rt<"row"<"col-sm-4"B><"col-sm-4"i><"col-sm-4"p>>',
                                 lengthMenu=  list(c(10, 25, 50, -1), 
                                                   c('10', '25', '50','All')),
                                 scrollCollapse= TRUE,
                                 lengthChange = TRUE, 
                                 widthChange= TRUE,
                                 rownames = TRUE))})
  
  
}
```

Images-

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a way to center the table caption on visible space, I can't help with that. I can offer an alternative working solution, though.

Instead of trying to center the title of the table, add a title outside of the table. I added the title to the `mainPanel` in the `ui`.

The code below includes your original caption and what I added. You can see it rendered in the first two images at the bottom of this post.

In the third image at the bottom of this answer, I removed your table caption.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

xyz_query <- dplyr::bind_cols(mtcars, mtcars)
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(), 
    navbarPage( 
      id = "navbar",
      title= "xyz",
      windowTitle = "xyz test",
      tabPanel("Dataset",
               div(style="display:inline-block",shinyWidgets::materialSwitch(inputId = "toggleSidebar", label = "Filter Panel: ",
                                                    value = TRUE, status = "warning")),
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   id = "Sidebar",
                   br(),
                   br()
                 ),
                               # this is where I added to your code
                 mainPanel(h3("MTCARS mtCARS mTcArS MTcars", align="center"),
                   id = "main_panel",
                   DT::DTOutput('panel1_data')
                 )
               )
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$toggleSidebar, {
      shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar", condition = input$toggleSidebar)
      if(!isTRUE(input$toggleSidebar)) {
        shinyjs::runjs("$('#main_panel').removeClass('col-sm-8').addClass('col-sm-12')")
      } else {
        shinyjs::runjs("$('#main_panel').removeClass('col-sm-12').addClass('col-sm-8')")
      }
    })
    output$panel1_data <- DT::renderDT(server = FALSE, {
      DT::datatable(xyz_query,
                    extensions = c('Buttons'),
                    caption = htmltools::tags$caption(style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center; color:black; font-size:150% ;',
                                                      'MTCARS mtCARS mTcArS MTcars'),
                    options = list(scrollY = 600,
                                   scrollX = TRUE,
                                   dom =  '<"float-left"l><"float-right"f>rt<"row"<"col-sm-4"B><"col-sm-4"i><"col-sm-4"p>>',
                                   lengthMenu=  list(c(10, 25, 50, -1), 
                                                     c('10', '25', '50','All')),
                                   scrollCollapse= TRUE,
                                   lengthChange = TRUE, 
                                   widthChange= TRUE,
                                   rownames = TRUE))})
  }
)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kat for your solution. Although this works, I was looking a way to adjust the caption itself because I have a collapsible row on top of this table. By adding `h3` there is now additional row for the title. With caption, title becomes part of the table and I don't have to worry about an extra row. Regardless, I can figure out something if I don't get any other response. However, for now I would like to wait for more answers. Thank you again, I gave a you a Vote up :)

Comment: Thank you Kat for helping out !! Take care.